# I accidentally deleted some autorun processes, and now can't restore Windows

Tags: windows, boot, autorun

I've downloaded a program that detects the autoruns on my system. I deleted some autorun processes from my system and now some good features of Windows have disappeared. More important than all of them right now is that I want to restore my system to factory.

This however gives me the error:

> [The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible 0xc000000e]

I then tried to use the backup DVDs, but Windows doesn't boot from the CD. When I select "boot from internal CD/DVD" it directs me to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Boot device selection happens long before autorun services.  I suspect you may have removed your restore partition or switched hard drives.  If that's the case then you can't perform a restore without boot CD/DVD.

Comment: I only have partitioned drive C.And I've not removed my recovery partition.

Comment: @reza:Then you've probably removed something else. Either way, the advice stands.  You'll need to boot into the bootCD and try to restore your old registry, if you have a backup.  I'm sure also the "program" you downloaded made a backup of the registry before making the changes.  I'd hunt that down as well.

Comment: I have a back up created by norton.I used this to restore my computer but in the middle of process the program wants me to continue on the boot conditon but my windows doesn't boot into that CD.There is not any boot problem because when I insert a windows CD my windows boots into that